# Issue in file selecting to stack in Registax5

Tags: astrophotography, image-stacking, deepskystacker

I have taken 1998 images of sun using a neural density filter. I preprocessed the images using PIPP and got a list of cropped images which were arranged in order of their quality. But then when I try to open all of them in Registax5 to stack them, I am unable to do so. When I select all the files, this is how the screen looks"
[image]

And then if I click "open", this is the error.
[image]
But I am perfectly able to open 1200 images(Approx) at once, no matter the top 1200 or the bottom. But If I am selecting more images, then the same issue occurs. What is the solution to this? What could be causing this problem? How can I stack 2000 images?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it's a basic customer support question, better addressed to the manufacturer/developer.

Comment: Never heard of that software, but it looks like there's a "version 6" available. Maybe you should upgrade.